How to prove this problem about ternary quadratic form?
Is this right? And how to prove it ?
For $n \equiv 1,2 \mod 4$
$$ \Bigg|\ \mathbb Z^3\cap\Big\{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\ \Big|\ 
a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2=n \Big\}\Bigg| \\
 =  \frac12\Bigg|\mathbb Z^3\cap\Big\{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\ \Big|\
 |a_1a_2|+|a_2a_3|+|a_1a_3|=n \Big\}\Bigg|
$$
Here $|\cdot| $denotes the cardinality of a set.
Denote the left hand side quantity by $r(n)$. In other words,  $r(n)$ means the number of ways $n$
can be written as sum of three square of integers.
My experiment on Mathematica is
here. In the picture, the first generating function is the generating function for the expression by sumf of three squares. The second generating function is half of the generating function of pairwise product absolute sum.
Notice that when $n \equiv 1,2 \mod 4$ the coefficients of $x^n$ of two functions (the generating function of both sides respectively) are equal.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The problem have been solved by @GH from MO : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/478999/how-to-prove-this-problem-about-ternary-quadratic-form#479008

I’m sorry, I misread. I thought you said for $n =1, 2, 4$. This was very unfortunate error on my part.

@davidlowryduda Don't worry about it. I am also interested in analytic number theory and automorphic forms. I am deeply attracted by the work of Sieberg and Vinogradov. Maybe we can talk about it later.
